# Twitter Bootstrap responsive utility class usage

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How are the Twitter Bootstrap responsive utility classes such as .visible-desktop supposed to be used. I have tried to follow the example on the Bootstrap web site,

```
<span class="visible-desktop">✔ Desktop</span>
```

on an image like this,

```
<span class="visible-desktop">
  <img src="<%=(image_path('green.jpg'))%>"></img>
</span>
```

but the image remains when I shrink the browser window to tablet or phone size.

Comment: Are you including the `bootstrap-responsive.css` stylesheet "after" the `bootstrap.css` stylesheet? or at all?

Comment: Yes, I have the stylesheets included correctly, and other responsive features are working.

Comment: Can you post your setup of how you are using it over at http://jsfiddle.net? That class is being explicitly hidden with the `!important` flag and should overwrite any other `display` properties in that element, so there must be something else.

Comment: I am using the Ruby Gem bootstrap-sass version 2.0.2 instead of the official bootstrap distribution, and going through the code I noticed that the responsive utility classes do not have the !important flag. I assume this corresponds to bootstrap 2.0.2. Does anyone know if this was a problem that was corrected in bootstrap 2.0.3?

Comment: The flag is available in the `bootstrap-responsive.css` ver2.0.3 stylesheet, http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css

Answer (score 12):

Just in case someone wants to do this with **Bootstrap 3.0**. Hey have changed these classes:

`.visible-phone` became `.visible-sm`

`.visible-tablet` became `.visible-md`

`.visible-desktop` became `.visible-lg`

`.hidden-phone` became `.hidden-sm`

`.hidden-tablet` became `.hidden-md`

`.hidden-desktop` became `.hidden-lg`

Usage:

```
<span class='hidden-sm hidden-md visible-lg'>
```

The Bootstrap 3.0 migration guide can be found [here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#migration).

Answer (score 6):

This is a great diagram explaining how to use these in bootstrap 3.1

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This works for me -

Try adding `.hidden-phone` and `.hidden-tablet` to your `span` class, like so:

```
<span class="visible-desktop hidden-phone hidden-tablet"> </span>
```

Comment: I would try updating Bootstrap before trying something like this. `.visible-destop` class is supposed to do the job of the other two classes mentioned in this answer, so in practice it should either be `.visible-destop` by itself or `.hidden-phone` and `.hidden-tablet` together

Answer (score 0):

Did you copy/paste your code? Because you have a typo...

```
<span class="visable-desktop">
```

should be

```
<span class="visible-desktop">
```

Answer (score 0):

the class `.visible-desktop` shouldn't be showing on tablets or phones if all the dependencies are in place and referred to correctly (CSS files, etc).

On this section on Bootstrap's own introductory documentation you can see a live example: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive

Try applying the class on a very simple tag and see if it works at all first. If it doesn't it won't work on any other tag. :)

Good luck!