# Bootstrap 3.1 visible-xs and visible-sm not working together

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a div that I want to show on sm and xs devices, it looks like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 visible-xs visible-sm">
   <a href="#">Item 1</a>
   <a href="#">Item 2</a>
   <a href="#">Item 3</a>
</div>
```

My bootstrap is loading from cdn without any customization.

This is supposed to show this div on xs and sm as stated on classes but the result is the sm class `display:none !important` is overriding the xs `display:block !important` when you go to xs size on the browser.

I tried to find out on bootstrap documentation but they only have a table that is not explaining how to use multiple visibility parameters on the same div.

Comment: Have you tried the other way with `hidden-md hidden-lg`?

Comment: I will try that now because I didn't. This looks like some kind of bug to me, at least there's a reason behind this behaviour.

Comment: That's not a bug, is the intended behavior. [Bootstrap Responsive utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities)

Comment: That worked @JuriRobl. I'd be happy if you put as answer so I can mark it as chosen. Thanks!

Comment: @azeós where can I read that this is an intended behaviour?. All I read there is that _Use a single or combination of the available classes for toggling content across viewport breakpoints._

Comment: Jaypee, my bad, you are right. I remembered different that table. BTW, that changed in 3.1.0, what you are trying work's in 3.0.3. But I always did it like @JuriRobl says.

Comment: No problem @azeós. Maybe I post on github so they can clarify this on documentation.

Comment: I am using Bootstrap 3.3.6... I think I have the desired behavior of visible only when `xs` and `sm` device sizes... is there any different between 3.1 and 3.3.6?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

If you want to show it at multiple sizes, don't use `visible-*` but instead hide the other sizes you don't want with `hidden-*`.
In this case: `hidden-md hidden-lg`

Comment: To clarify, what's happening is that one of the visible-* classes is forcing a "display: none!important" that overrides the other one. It's applying a style any time the media query *doesn't* match. When you use hidden, it only applies when it does so no side-effects.

Comment: What if another interval is added to bootstrap? Then every site has faulty css.

Comment: check official **responsive utilities classes** [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22079665/2218697), hope helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

When I face issues like this, I would simply prefer to use my own custom media query to manipulate the visibility of an element.

```
.someclass{
    display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
   .someclass{
      display: normal!important;
   }
}
```

Or if you want to re-use this, then define a custom class such as:

```
.visible-tablet-mobile{
    display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
   .visible-tablet-mobile{
        display: normal!important;
   }
}
```

and re-use it instead of giving your div two visibility classes at a time.

Comment: Yes, that's okay, but I was trying to stick to bootstrap grid.

Comment: Check @Juri Robl comment, that's probably what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes @azeós I'm checking that now. Thanks.

Comment: you are still with grid. you just override the existing viability classes for your own convenience.

Comment: `display: normal` doesn't exist, you are just giving an invalid rule and the browser will fallback on default

Answer (score 3):

You must add one value from:

```
`.visible-*-block` for `display: block;`
`.visible-*-inline` for `display: inline;`
`.visible-*-inline-block` for `display: inline-block;`
```

In this case you will have something like this:

`<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 visible-xs-block visible-sm-block">`

Keep up the good work :)

Answer (score 2):

Bootstraps works with classes that go from the specified width-class and up. For example if you put `col-sm-4`, this simply forces it to be 4 columns wide for the sm-width and wider.

In your case a simple `class="col-xs-4 hidden-md hidden-lg"` should be enough to get your desired solution.

The reason your first solution didn't work, is that you specified `visible-xs` before `visible-sm`. Which forces the sm class onto it, making it invisible on the xs-width. As this is specified in the stock bootstrap css.

Edit: For those who are using Bootstrap 4 this could be achieved with just `class="col-4 d-md-none"`