# Bootstrap 3 Grid - hide/show columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using the Bootstrap 3 grid to hide/show nav bar content based on whether or not the user is using an extra small device.

I'm using `.hidden-xs` and `.visible-xs` classes. These classes appropriately hide/show the content, but I'm running into two problems:

(1) Hiding the content also shrinks the column spacing by `.col-xs-5` because the div is hidden. I tried adding `.visible-xs` to a subsequent div and using `.col-xs-5` to make up the empty space. This works, but only if I place content inside the divs. I just want the columns to be spaced out.

(2) On XS view size, the final item on the Nav bar "Nav" jumps to the next row. I have only accounted for 12 total columns.

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matt81m/2sx2rh0n/2/). I'm trying to nly show "Welcome" on large view and show nothing on XS view.

Comment: did you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21667100/bootstrap-3-1-visible-xs-and-visible-sm-not-working-together

Comment: I'm not trying to use multiple visibility parameters on the same div. I'm using two different divs.

Answer (score 0):

I here's an idea, you can try instead of adding content. This CSS trick uses :before and :after CSS pseudo-classes.

```
.no_content {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 151px;
  height: 35px;
  background: transparent url(tape.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}

<div class="no_content"></div>
```

Comment: I can also add `<p>&nbsp;</p` and it does the trick. Surely there is a better Bootstrap way to do this...

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the grid system further.  I believe there is an offset that you can use to offset the div like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-5></div>
  <div class="col-xs-2></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `pull-right` bootstrap class instead of trying to make empty div's fill in the space.

Completely remove the div you added in item (1) to "make up the space".  On the div containing "Nav" set the class as `pull-right col-xs-1`.  So the code from your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2sx2rh0n/7/) becomes:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row" id="header">

     <div class="col-xs-5" id="brand-wrapper">
           <div class="brand">Brand</div>
     </div>

    <!-- Hidden on XS Devices -->
    <div class="hidden-xs col-xs-5">
        <p>
         Welcome
        </p>
    </div>

    <!-- Nav -->
    <div class="pull-right col-xs-1" id="toggle-wrapper">
        <p>Nav</p>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```