# visible-xs-block not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

i'm creating a site with bootstrap, and i want some div to show only in extra small devices, i'm using the `visible-xs-block` class im my div, but don't work.

Some one now why not work?

this is my code:

```
<div class="search-block-wrapper visible-xs-block">
     <div class="search-block">
        <input type="text" class="search-block-input form-control" placeholder="Search..."/>
     </div>
</div>
```

But, this div still showing in large widths.

And, if i use `hidden-sm, hidden-md, and hidden-lg` instead use `visible-xs-block`, everything works.

Comment: "And, if i use hidden-sm, hidden-md, and hidden-lg instead use visible-xs-block, everything works." - Seems to me you have your answer. Remember this is **mobile-first**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 3.1 visible-xs and visible-sm not working together](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21667100/bootstrap-3-1-visible-xs-and-visible-sm-not-working-together)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't work? All work. Check it! Try change size window!
http://jsfiddle.net/9EQeg/166/

```
<div class="search-block-wrapper visible-xs-block">
    <div class="search-block">
        <input type="text" class="search-block-input form-control" placeholder="Search..."/>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you won't use this solution, use hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg

xs - Extra small devices Phones (<768px)